# Get Data With Right Join or Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query below

```
SELECT  
    TRX.TrnNo TerminationID, 
    TRX.FullName EmployeeName, 
    TRX.EmployeeID SN, 
    TRX.Division, 
    TRX.LastDayDate LWD, 
    TRX.EffectiveDate ETD, 
    IIF(TRX.Type = 'TYP1','SAP','TRACE') Type, 
    TRX.Status, 
    MU.EmployeeID PICEmployeeID, 
    MU.Name PICName, 
    MG.Name PICGroupName,
    MG.ID PICGroupID
FROM UserLocation ul
JOIN MasterUsers mu ON ul.xupj = mu.XUPJ
JOIN UserRole UR ON UR.XUPJ = MU.XUPJ
JOIN MasterUserGroups MUG ON MUG.UserXUPJ = MU.XUPJ
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT Tr.TrnNo, Tr.EmployeeID, tr.FullName, ISNULL(mu.Location, em.Location_Id) LocationID, Division, tr.LastDayDate, tr.EffectiveDate, tr.Type, tr.Status
            FROM EmployeeMaster em
            LEFT JOIN MasterUsers mu on em.employee_id = mu.employeeid
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT * FROM TrnRequest tr 
                WHERE (tr.[DeletedDate] IS NULL) AND (tr.[Status] IN (N'DRFT', N'NEW')) AND (tr.[Status] IS NOT NULL) AND (tr.[DeletedDate] IS NULL)
                AND em.Employee_Id = tr.EmployeeID
            ) Tr
        ) X WHERE ul.Location_Id = X.LocationID
) TRX
RIGHT JOIN MasterGroups MG ON  MUG.GroupID = MG.ID
WHERE mu.IsActive = 1 AND UR.RoleID = 2
AND TRX.TrnNo IN ('TRM-1007')
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

As seen above, I added a right join to MasterGroups. This is what MasterGroups looks like:

[image]

I want to show all the `PICGroupName` from `MasterGroups` to check if the transaction has all `PICGroupName` or not. I tried `left join` or `right join`, but it seems look like `inner join` if we see the result

How can I manage that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please do not use images, use tabular text (markdown is available). 2) Please ensure you provide a [mre] with emphasis on minimal, i.e. the minimum required to illustrate your problem, including sample raw data (raw as in before query, not actual data). and desired results

Comment: You outer `WHERE` pretty much filter out all the null values, ie turning your `RIGHT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems look like inner join if we see the result

This happens because of the `WHERE` conditions.
Think about it, when the transaction does not link to a specific PICGroup record then all none PICGroup columns will be null, causing the `WHERE` conditions to evaluate to False.

Solutions:

1 Add `OR TRX.TrnNo IS NULL` condition

```
WHERE ( mu.IsActive = 1 AND UR.RoleID = 2
        AND TRX.TrnNo IN ('TRM-1007'))
    OR TRX.TrnNo IS NULL
```

2 Try moving `WHERE` conditions to their respective `JOINS`

```
FROM UserLocation ult
-- Note the AND mu.IsActive = 1
JOIN MasterUsers mu ON ul.xupj = mu.XUPJ AND mu.IsActive = 1
-- Note the AND UR.RoleID = 2
JOIN UserRole UR ON UR.XUPJ = MU.XUPJ AND UR.RoleID = 2
JOIN MasterUserGroups MUG ON MUG.UserXUPJ = MU.XUPJ
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT Tr.TrnNo, Tr.EmployeeID, tr.FullName, ISNULL(mu.Location, em.Location_Id) LocationID, Division, tr.LastDayDate, tr.EffectiveDate, tr.Type, tr.Status
            FROM EmployeeMaster em
            LEFT JOIN MasterUsers mu on em.employee_id = mu.employeeid
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT * FROM TrnRequest tr 
                WHERE (tr.[DeletedDate] IS NULL) AND (tr.[Status] IN (N'DRFT', N'NEW')) AND (tr.[Status] IS NOT NULL) AND (tr.[DeletedDate] IS NULL)
                AND em.Employee_Id = tr.EmployeeID
                -- Note the AND TRX.TrnNo IN ('TRM-1007')
                AND tr.TrnNo IN ('TRM-1007')
            ) Tr
        ) X WHERE ul.Location_Id = X.LocationID
) TRX
RIGHT JOIN MasterGroups MG ON  MUG.GroupID = MG.ID
-- No more WHERE clause
```